# Обрезать фон ScroolView

Tags: java, android

Есть ScRoolView со вложенным vertical Linear Layout. Фоном у этого Linear - длинное изображение (нужно, чтобы при прокрутке оно менялось). 
Все отлично прокручивается, показывается текст, фото, НО в конце, когда прокручивается последняя надпись на Linear LAyout, продолжает скроллиться фон (изображение 400 x 7000). Как сделать так, чтобы в конце, когда пользователь доскроллит до последней надписи, фон остановился.  Есть какие-то варианты кроме "обрезать фото на фоне"?

Comment: Я, конечно, не берусь за ваш конкретный случай говорить, так как конкретики мало, но вообще, такое огромное изображение использовать нерационально. Вы уже пробовали на практике это? Приложение не падало? В моей практике, не самые слабые девайсы падали на картинках >4000px по одной из сторон из-за ограничения OpenGL.

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

1. Имеющийся **LinearLayout** с фоном поместить **под** ScrollView.
2. В слушателе прокрутки **ScrollView** двигать его.
3. Содержимое же ScrollView обернуть LinearLayout  с высотой="wrap_content"

---

Наверняка с помощью **CoordinatorLayout** из **Android Design Support Library** реализовать требуемое поведение не сложно.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Могли бы поподробнее про второй пункт? Не понимаю, как его реализовать. Это делать в настройках разметки или в java?

Comment: Это в коде надо делать. Пример: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23365539/3212712